# Condition to check if element is present in DOM

Tags: java, selenium

I am using `if` block to check if product is in stock or out of stock. but it is not executing the `else` block , also I don't want to put `else` part in catch block.

I have used `isDisplayed`, `isEnabled` but still it is not working.

```
try {
    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Currently unavailable.')]"))
            .isEnabled()) {
        o1.put("STOCK", "Out of Stock");
    } else {
        o1.put("STOCK", "In Stock");
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use [`findElements()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method whenever checking for presence of element
because if timeout occurs it will return empty list instead exception and you are saved from handling the exception in case of `findElements()`. So remove the `try catch`you don't need it with below code.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Currently unavailable.')]")).size() > 0) {
    o1.put("STOCK", "Out of Stock");
} else {
    o1.put("STOCK", "In Stock");
}
```

As you have mentioned in your code in if condition, it will always raise exception if element it not found before reaching to the method `.isEnabled()`.

Answer (score 1):

To check the condition you need to check the visibility of the element, so, instead of using `isDisplayed()` and `isEnabled()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
try {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Currently unavailable.')]")));
    o1.put("STOCK", "Out of Stock");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    o1.put("STOCK", "In Stock");
}
```

**Note**: If you are using `try-catch {}` block, you don't need `if-else {}` block which will be an overhead.